Why is the entry method called twice?
I have a piece of codes as below. Have anyone experienced with this issue? Thanks!
def update() {
    String metadata = request.reader.text
    logger.info("Updating the submission: $metadata")
    Map<String, Object> working = [isUpdate: true, isUpdateOnExistingModel: true, isAmend: false, isMetadataSubmission: false]
    if (metadata) {
        makeSubmission(metadata, working)
    } else {
        logger.debug("Cannot update the model as requested because of the empty input.")
    }
}

private void makeSubmission(String metadata, Map working) {
    String uuid = request.getHeader("SubmissionFolder")
    working.put("submissionFolder", uuid)
    def currentUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
    working.put("submitterInfo", [userRealName: currentUser?.person?.userRealName,
                                      username: currentUser.username, email: currentUser.email])
    Map map
    try {
        submissionService.buildFromJSONFile(metadata, working)
    } catch (Exception e) {
       logger.error e.getMessage()
    } finally {
       working["repository_files"] = null
       if (!working["repository_files"]) {
           String msg = "Cannot find the model files. The submission process has to be terminated!"
           logger.error(msg)
           map = [message: msg, status: 400]
       } else {
           doValidateSubmissionData(working)
           map = doCompleteSubmission()
       }
    }

    withFormat {
        json { render map as JSON }
        xml { render map as XML }
        '*' { render status: 415, view: "/errors/error415" }
    }
}

When I enable the debugging mode (in IntelliJ IDEA), the entry point (e.g., update) is invoked twice. See the screen recording here.

Which http verb are you using? How are you calling the endpoint?
I'd recommend you check if Chrome preloading pages cause it. Some GET routes might be "activated" twice because of it.

